# Drupal 8 REST add custom error messages to existing core /entity/user/ resource

Tags: 8

I am using drupal 8 rest and I want to be able to do a few computations and return custom json messages as per the defined condition when posting a user. I am using the already existing `/entity/user/` resource provided by core out of the box. I tried to create a custom module and tried to use the `Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse` class in the module file like below:

```
function magri_rest_user_presave($account) {

    if (isset($account->field_region->value)) {

        $taxonomy_query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term');
        $taxonomy_query ->condition('vid', "region")
            ->condition('name', $account->field_region->value);
        $tids = $taxonomy_query->execute();

        $tid = array_values($tids)[0];


        if($tid){
            //set taxonomy ref field on user entity
            $account->field_region_tax->target_id = $tid;

        }else{
            die;
            $response = ['message' => 'Region not found'];
            return new ResourceResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not stop the rest call to return the custom message. Is there a way I can archive this withouts creating my own custom rest plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a response from a presave hook. You can however throw an exception, which in a json route will return a json error message:

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException('Region not found!');
```

If you want to change the default error response, implement an exception subscriber to catch this exception and return your own response.

For reference the default exception handler: [ExceptionJsonSubscriber::on4xx](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21ExceptionJsonSubscriber.php/function/ExceptionJsonSubscriber%3A%3Aon4xx/8.7.x)

Comment: Thank you, but this just throws the exception its not returning a json error message

Comment: If you have a json route, what I don't know, then Drupal can out-of-the-box return a json error message, as explained in the second part of my answer. In other cases you might need to implement your own exception subscriber.

Comment: okay maybe if you point me in the right direction. What is a json route? I am using the rest module, together with REST UI and RESTful Web Services.

Comment: Add `?_format=json` to the requested url.

Comment: yet it has. It is actually the only allowed format on all my configured resources. hal_json and xml are disabled.

Comment: What does the exception say exactly? Maybe it is not a 4xx exception.

Comment: ```Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: Region not found! in magri_rest_user_presave() (line 59 of /var/www/html/modules/custom/magri_rest/magri_rest.module).```

Comment: When I throw this exception in a json route I get this response: `{ message: "Region not found!" }`

Comment: You are throwing it from a custom module file? All I am getting at postman is ```website has encountred an error...``` and I get the exeption in the logs

Comment: `website has encountred an error...` is happening when no event subscriber did catch the exception. But I don't understand why ExceptionJsonSubscriber::on4xx didn't handle it, in my Drupal it does.

Comment: ok thank you for your patience. I will mark your answer as correct and I will research further on this.

Comment: I think this is been caused because I first encounter ```Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: Internal Server Error``` before the ```NotFoundHttpException```. Do you know how I can stop this behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98332/discussion-between-tendaitakas-and-4k4).